# dispatchKeyEvent doesn't effect to EditText inside PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I have popup window that contains some EditTexts. I want to create my custom numerical keyboard inside the popup window. So I have 10 buttons that represent digits 0-9. Inside buttons' onClickListener I trying to dispatch key event

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0));
}
```

but it doesn't effect to EditTexts. I tried to do it with focusable equals true and false, but the result is the same. When I am trying to dispatch key event in the main layout of activity it works well, so what I should change to make my code work inside popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried requesting focus on the EditTexts? Not only using

```
editText.setFocusable(true);
```

but also

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

I think it's also possible that is not working because you're not injecting a DOWN event first. Try the following:

```
Instrumentation mInstrumentation = new Instrumentation();
final Thread t = new Thread() {
     public void run(){ 
              mInstrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0);               
     };
t.start();
```

This will inject an event which will be processed by the view that has the focus

Comment: Why the negative vote? Specially with no comment attached